# Horizontal image grid with rows in power bi

Tags: powerbi

[image: dashboard example]

This is my current dashboard, for the images i use the extra plugin, image grid.

But I now see image grid does not support tooltip function.

Does anyone know how to make image grids like this without image grid, or adding tooltip to image grid? (this is just 1 column of image urls)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also trying to get a grid of images working without the plug in ( I need to drill-through which I can't see an option for).
Wondering how you solved this?